# How to display checkbox in CakePHP 3.x? Or template to display Check boxes in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have code that I'd like to display:-

```
<div class="row form-group m-form__group m-login__form-sub">
  <div class="col m--align-left">
    <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--light">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agree">I Agree the
      <a href="#" class="m-link m-link--focus">terms and conditions</a>.
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <span class="m-form__help"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

So how do I convert it using the FormHelper. Or how to create template for same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i Mentioned cakephp Way of creating checkbox.Try it.Hope it Works.

```
<div class="row form-group m-form__group m-login__form-sub">
  <div class="col m--align-left">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('agree', array(
     'type'=>'checkbox','label'=>'I Agree The'));?>
    <a href="#" class="m-link m-link--focus">terms and conditions</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i take both div inside $this->Form->input??

Comment: @a.shah Yes you can by using templating, please refer the doc https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#moving-checkboxes-radios-outside-of-a-label

Comment: You can use  <?= $this->Form->checkbox('agree', ['hiddenField' => false, 'value' => '1']); ?> .